# Add post category to latest post block in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am editing the latest-blog.php file for WordPress and I have two goals.

1. I would like the post category to be displayed and have a class of category assigned to it.
2. I would like to assign a class to the thumbnail, the title and the excerpt so I can style them.

The code below is where I believe the changes need to made

```
foreach ( $recent_posts as $post ) {
    $post_id = $post['ID'];

    $title = get_the_title( $post_id );
    if ( ! $title ) {
        $title = __( '(Untitled)' );
    }
    
    $post_url = get_permalink( $post_id );
    
    $text = get_post( $post_id );
    $text = $text->post_content;
    $text = wp_trim_words( $text, 25, '... <a class="subtitle-red"  style="display:block;" href="'.$post_url.'">read&nbsp;full&nbsp;article</a>' );
    $excerpt = $text;
            
    $list_items_markup .= sprintf(
        '<li>
        <a href="%2$s">%1$s%3$s</a><p>%4$s</p>',
        get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id ),
        esc_url( get_permalink( $post_id ) ),
        esc_html( $title ), 
        $excerpt
    );
            
    if ( isset( $attributes['displayPostDate'] ) && $attributes['displayPostDate'] ) {
        $list_items_markup .= sprintf(
            '<time datetime="%1$s" class="wp-block-latest-posts__post-date">%2$s</time>',
            esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c', $post_id ) ),
            esc_html( get_the_date( '', $post_id ) )
        );
    }
    $list_items_markup .= "</li>\n";
}
```

As this is a core WP file editing it really isn't the best idea so an extra question... could this be done via functions.php instead?

Thanks

TJ

Comment: Can you please tell, where exactly this file is located? You said it was a “core file”, but I can’t even find it in my WP installations right now. Are you sure this is not rather part of some specific theme?

Comment: Hi CBroe,

The file lives in wp-includes>blocks.

Comment: Overwriting such an include file is not a good idea - not least, because any further WP update will overwrite your changes again. If this can’t be achieved by hooking into the filters that modify the output of any of the functions involved - then you’re probably better off creating your own block based on this.

Comment: Yeah, I mention that changing a core file is a no-no. But in this instance it is fine. A quick fix is needed rather than hooking into filters or building a new block - both of which are new to me.